# Sharepoint 2013 web application migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to move my sharepoint webapplication from one server to another.

I have more than 70 pages and 15 visual webparts, which are used in pages.

My question is how can i move application with all pages and webparts and content. Without any loss of content.

Thanks.

Comment: If the servers are in the same farm, there's nothing you need to do besides start the Microsoft Foundation Web Service on the additional farm server. Or are you moving to a different farm?

Answer (score 3):

If you will migrate a web application to another server in another farm, you should first make sure that the SharePoint Build number of destination environment must be higher than or matched with the build number of the source environment, to make sure that check.

- [Find the latest Cumulative Update / Farm Patch Level that has been installed in a SharePoint Farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-the-latest-cu-farm-patch-level-that-already-installed-in-your-sharepoint-farm/)
- [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)

Second, you have two methods to migrate your web application

1. **Database-upgrade**

   - In source farm, Take a backup of the content database via SQL Management Studio.
   - In destination farm, Create A web application, Site Collection.
   - In destination farm, Dismount the web application content database, via this command

`Dismount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentdBName>"`

- In destination , via SQL Management Studio , Restore the content database.
- In destination , Mount it to the created web application,

`Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName`

- In destination farm, Change Site Collection administrator to avoid the access permission issue. by going to site Setting > Site Collection Administrator > Set the site admin account in Dev.
- Finally, deploy your custom web part solutions as mentioned at [Install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) Solution Package using SharePoint Shell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)

For more details check [Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

**Note:** if your web application has multiple content database, you should backup all the content databases via SQL Management Studio and restore them to the new farm then mount them to the new web application.

2. **BackUp and Restore**

   - Take a backup from the old web application.

`Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} -Item <WebApplicationName>` for more details check [Back up a Web application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748623%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Then restore a web application as mentioned at [Restore a Web application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748618(v=office.14).aspx)

If your web application has only one site collection do the following:

- Take a backup of site collection from the old web application.

> ```
> Backup-SPSite -Identity http://siteURL -Path "C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"
> ```

- Create a new web application.
- Restore backup in the new web application.

> Restore-SPSite -Identity http://url -Path
>   "C:\MoveSiteCollection.bak"

- Finally, deploy your custom web part solutions as mentioned at [Install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) Solution Package using SharePoint Shell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)