# Best approach for a SharePoint server rebuild - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

What would be the best approach for complete SharePoint 2013 servers rebuild ?

Comment: Do you mean you need to clone the current SharePoint server to another server?

Comment: What rebuild means? Are you trying to recover it from backup? What type of backup u have? Any service application recovery etc?

Comment: Building the SharePoint servers from the scratch and migrating the content.

Answer (score 2):

**As a short answer:** Building a fresh server from scratch!

**#Some instructions to clone your server:**

**In source server/farm,**

- Take a full backup from your current farm.
- Take a full backup of SharePoint content databases in case you want to use Database-Attach method.
- Backup all the deployed SharePoint solutions (WSP) in your farm if exist.
- Determine the SQL version.
- [Determine the build number and the latest CU installed on your source farm be installed on your destination farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/).

---

**In destination server/farm,**

- Install a fresh SharePoint environment

  - Windows, SQL Server.
- Install and Configure SharePoint Server 2013 with the same source Enterprise Edition.
- Install the latest Cumulative Update that already installed in source farm.

> **Note:** You should be aware of the destination farm build number must be higher than or equal to the build number of source farm.

- Install the corresponding language pack that already installed on your source farm.
- Create a Web Application and Site Collection.
- Provision the corresponding Application Services.
- Restore your backup as I mentioned at [Sharepoint 2013 web application migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207762/sharepoint-2013-web-application-migration)

Also check

- [Configure a new SharePoint install with existing databases](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/configure-a-new-sharepoint-install-with-existing-databases)
- [CLONING SharePoint 2013 ENVIRONMENT](http://www.meritsolutions.com/microsoft-sharepoint/cloning-sharepoint-2013-environment/)